# How to search through dynamic table vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

So I am creating tables in vue using loops, i.e. anyone can upload a table and view it.

```
<el-table :data="filtered"  border style="width: 100%" height="500" @selection-change="handleSelectionChange" @header-click="contextmenu">
  <el-table-column type="selection" width="55"/>
  <el-table-column  fixed v-for="col in columns" :prop="col.field" :label="col.field" :key="col.field"/>
  <el-table-column>
    <template #header>
        <el-input v-model="searchQuery" size="small" placeholder="Type to search" />
      </template>
      <template #default="scope">
        <el-button size="small" type="danger" @click="handleDelete(scope.$index, scope.row)">Delete</el-button>
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
  
  </el-table>
  <el-button type="warning" round v-on:click="getdata(selected_data,source)">Update-Data</el-button>
</div>
```

I and trying to implement a search feature that is dynamic, i.e. it can search through all the columns of any table uploaded by user.
I saw some solutions online but they are for fixed tables.
I also tried writing a loop and returning the data

```
computed: {
    filtered (){
      if(this.searchQuery){
      return this.d.filter((item)=>{
        for(let i=0;i<this.columns.length;i++){
          const x=this.columns[0].field //I have an array columns which has all the columns inside 
                                          //of it in a dictionary
          console.log(item.x.startsWith(this.searchQuery)) //this gives an error *Cannot read 
                                                             //properties of undefined (reading 
                                                             //'startsWith')*
        }
        return item.Name.startsWith(this.searchQuery); // and this line works perfectly fine, if I  
                                                          //the table has a column named **Name**
      })
      }else{
        return this.d; //d is the data array
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there a way I can search through all the columns of any table uploaded by the user?
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what's `item.x`, does this property exist on `item` object? Also, what's the output if you use `item.Name` in place of `item.x` and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `item[x]` instead of `item.x`.